# CorePlot horizontal gradient on axis

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I'm trying to create a horizontal gradient on my y axis in CorePlot:

```
CPTGradient *axisGradient = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:[CPTColor redColor] endingColor:[CPTColor yellowColor]];
axisGradient.angle = 180.f;

CPTMutableLineStyle *axisStyle = [y.axisLineStyle mutableCopy];
axisStyle.lineWidth = 6.f;
axisStyle.lineGradient = axisGradient;

y.axisLineStyle = axisStyle;
```

No matter what I set the gradient angle to the gradient is vertical.  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it looks like that is the property that needs to be changed to give the axis a gradient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Core Plot draws gradient line fills along the line path. If you want a tall, skinny rectangle filled with a gradient that fades from one color at the top to another at the bottom, use a plot space annotation. Create a `CPTBorderedLayer` for the annotation content and give it a gradient fill (`[CPTFill fillWithGradient:axisGradient]`).

Answer (score 1):

for horizontal  gradient you can use

```
CPTColor *areaColorStart       = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.74 green:0.78 blue:0.82 alpha:1];
CPTColor *areaColorEnd     = [CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:0.9 green:0.91 blue:0.92 alpha:.2];
CPTGradient *areaGradient1 = [CPTGradient gradientWithBeginningColor:areaColorStart endingColor:areaColorEnd];
areaGradient1.angle = 0.0f;
CPTFill *areaGradientFill = [CPTFill fillWithGradient:areaGradient1];
plot.areaFill       = areaGradientFill;
plot.areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromFloat(yRange);
```

hope it will help.